# what does start/wait means in batch file

Tags: batch-file

In batch file, what does start/wait means

Example:

```
ECHO start/wait C:\\Example.exe
```

I am trying to run an exe, so what does start/wait indicates over here?

Answer (score 3):

`/wait` forces the batch file to halt processing until the called program has finished executing.

(This can be useful, for example, if you are loading multiple items in your windows Startup folder, and the nature of the programs require that one be finished before the next starts loading. Put them all in a single batch file, using the /wait parameter, and only put a shortcut to the batch file in the Startup folder.) Command line parameters of the START command can be combined in a single line. Example:

```
START /max /wait NOTEPAD.EXE SOME.TXT
```

Source: http://aumha.org/a/batches.php